# Angular 8 How to Implement if elseif else statement

Tags: angular

I am new to Angular 8. I using Angular 8. Any help or hint would be greatly appreciated it!!

I trying to implement the following pseudo code:

```
if (condition1)
{
    print1
}
else if (condition2)
{
    print2
}
else
{
    print3
}
```

Here is the code that I am able to implement only `if else`

```
<ng-container *ngIf="(5>1);then resultOutOfRange else resultNA;">
</ng-container>
<ng-template #resultOutOfRange>
    <td  class="help-block">Result out of Range </td> 
</ng-template>
<ng-template #resultNA>
    <td>Result N/A</td>
</ng-template>
```

Comment: Either nest another ngIf inside your else template or use ngswitch if possible

Comment: Try chaining (condition1) ? #template1 : (condition2) ? #template2 : #templateDefault

Comment: Bryan60, I cannot use ngswitch because my conditions are actually very complicated. Can you please explain further how to "nest another ngIf inside your else template"?

Comment: If your logic is complex then do not model it in html. Use your component code, that is why it is there. Model the "complex" logic in your component (maybe in a method or in OnInit etc) and then designate a value to use in your template code that you can switch on.

Comment: @Igor's approach is the correct one IMO. complex conditionals don't belong in template

Comment: If your template code is getting ugly complex then it is time to split that into multiple components that can be called from the parent. Coding is all about managing complexity and abstracting a problem until you have manageable smaller parts that are maintainable and can be more easily modeled.

Answer (score 12):

option 1: nested ngIf:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="condition1; then true1 else block2"></ng-container>
<ng-template #true1>true1</ng-template>
<ng-template #block2>
  <ng-container *ngIf="condition2; then true2 else true3"></ng-container>
  <ng-template #true2>true2</ng-template>
  <ng-template #true3>true3</ng-template>
</ng-template>
```

or alternatively, if possible, use ngSwitch:

```
<div [ngSwitch]="switchCondition">
  <ng-container *ngSwitchCase="case1">true1</ng-container>
  <ng-container *ngSwitchCase="case2">true2</ng-container>
  <ng-container *ngSwitchCase="case3">true3</ng-container>
</div>
```

ngSwitch works in cases where you need to switch based on a certain value, you could work your code to set some variable based on the result of whatever conditionals by assignign `switchCondition` in your else if block like:

```
if (condition1) {
  this.switchCondition = 'case1'
} else if (condition2) {
  this.switchCondition = 'case2'
} else {
  this.switchCondition = 'case3'
}
```

put that in some function and call when appropriate.

Comment: Hi Bryan60, your solution is a "if condition1; then true1 else block2". I need a "if condition1 then true1 elseif condition2 then true2   or if elseif else?

Comment: read the code. block 2 evaluates condition2 to choose a template. this creates an if else if else conditional

Comment: Good answer, nice and simple. +1

Answer (score 5):

You are looking for a `if/else` block and then another `if/else` that is nested. There is no way to stack them like there is in javascript unless you have an atomic value in which case you can use `ngSwitch` which is similar to a switch/case statement.

```
<ng-container *ngIf="CONDITION1; else resultNA;">
  <p>Condition 1 is true</p>
</ng-container>

<ng-template #resultNA>
    <ng-container *ngIf="CONDITION 2; else otherBlock;">
        <p>Condition 2 is true</p>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-template #otherBlock>
      <p>No conditions are true</p>
    </ng-template>
</ng-template>
```

### Edit

> "I cannot use ngswitch because my conditions are actually very complicated."...

In this case I would recommend you take advantage of the fact you have component code (typescript). Write your logic there and then consume it in the HTML template, this will make your code more maintanable and easier to read.

Example *keep in mind you do not have to do this in the OnInit, it can be a method that is called as well or something else that changes as a value changes).*

*component.ts*

```
displayValue: number;
ngOnInit() {
  displayValue = /*your logic here that dictates what it should be*/.
}
```

*.html*

```
<container-element [ngSwitch]="displayValue">
   <some-element *ngSwitchCase="1">...</some-element>
   <some-element *ngSwitchCase="2">...</some-element>
   <some-element *ngSwitchCase="3">...</some-element>

   <some-element *ngSwitchDefault>...</some-element>
</container-element>
```

See also https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf and https://angular.io/api/common/NgSwitch